# Not able to import maven projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, maven-plugin

Getting the internal error when i try to import the maven project from my local machine.
[image: Internal error]

Should import successfully.

Comment: Check the path of the file 'poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar', the error says it contains some invalid characters.

Comment: Is there a settings.xml file in your .m2 folder?

Comment: No, i dont see that file in the .m2 folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the project folder via terminal.
Execute this command from inside:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to

1. Delete the 'poi-ooxml' folder
2. Reimport the project

Comment: Getting the same error even i with deleting both Poi-ooxml and scheme folder. @sunil Nalluru.

Answer (score 0):

base on the error message, looks like your repository path has a extra char '>'.

Should be: C:\Users\xxxx.m2\repository\org...

But Eclipse read: C:\Users\xxxx.m2\reposoitory**>**org

this path should be set with maven setting.xml, so suggest:

1. make sure the maven pack from apache offical site
2. override the setting.xml, under the maven_install_foleder/conf
3. check the Eclipse property settings about maven, if something override the repository path with a extra charareter

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the `.m2` folder and tried to import the project then it started to work correctly. Also  execute  `mvn clean intsall -u` in the project folder.